# Image processing (WinRT and C#) - images to video

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-runtime

Is there a way to process frames from a stream(or image file or video file) and save the frames in encoded video file without using Media Foundation API. I am not familiar with C++ and COM technology, so I ask is there any way to make video stream from set of images with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible with some .NET wrappers for Media Foundation. Perhaps SharpDX has them.